# Where to store data common to an app in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a variable which is used in all my 10 pages, where should I store it so that it is accessible by all pages? The same task can be accomplished in iOS by saving the variable in `APPDELEGATE`. What is the solution in windows phone?

Comment: Which language are you using? in C# you can use the App.cs or the Isolated Storage

Comment: Ok!! If i am saving a variable in App.xaml.cs then how can i refer it in page1??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should take a look at [some background reading](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage) to help

Sample code for IsolatedStorageSettings
Hope this will help you

```
public class AppSettings
    {
        // Our settings
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings;

        // The key names of our settings
        const List<String> PropertyIdList           = null;
        const List<String> FavPropertyIdList        = null;
        const string SearchSource                   = null;
        const string[] Suggestions                  = null;
        const string PropertyId                     = null;
        const string AgentContactInfo               = null;
        const string AgentShowPhoto                 = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that gets the application settings. 
        /// </summary>
        public AppSettings()
        {
            // Get the settings for this application.
            settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update a setting value for our application. If the setting does not
        /// exist, then add the setting.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Key"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
        {
            bool valueChanged = false;

            // If the key exists
            if (settings.Contains(Key))
            {
                // If the value has changed
                if (settings[Key] != value)
                {
                    // Store the new value
                    settings[Key] = value;
                    valueChanged = true;
                }
            }
            // Otherwise create the key.
            else
            {
                settings.Add(Key, value);
                valueChanged = true;
            }
            return valueChanged;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the current value of the setting, or if it is not found, set the 
        /// setting to the default setting.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="Key"></param>
        /// <param name="defaultValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string Key, T defaultValue)
        {
            T value;

            // If the key exists, retrieve the value.
            if (settings.Contains(Key))
            {
                value = (T)settings[Key];
            }
            // Otherwise, use the default value.
            else
            {
                value = defaultValue;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According your comment, if you have a public property like:

```
public string MyStaticVariable { get; set; }
MyStaticVariable = "SomeValue";
```

defined in your App.xaml.cs, you can access it in every page by:

```
App.MyStaticVariable;
```

My opinion: If you are talking about 1 variable which can be defined at startup of your app, the Isolated Storage is just overkill.